# C++11 std::thread giving error: no matching function to call std::thread::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I'm testing c++11 threads with this code, but when creating the thread, I'm having the error **no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread()'**.

It's like if there was something wrong with the function I'm giving to std::thread ctr, but I don't see how it's wrong. It is incompleted, but it looks right to me:

Header:

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_H
#define CONNECTION_H

#include <thread>
#include <mysql++.h>

class Connection
{
public:
    Connection(std::string mysqlUser, std::string mysqlPassword);
    ~Connection();

private:
    std::string mysqlUser;
    std::string mysqlPassword;
    std::string mysqlIP;
    int mysqlPort;

    mysqlpp::Connection mysqlConnection;
    std::thread connectionThread;

    void threadLoop();
};

#endif // CONNECTION_H
```

Source:

```
#include "connection.h"

Connection::Connection(std::string mysqlUser, std::string mysqlPassword)
{
    this->mysqlUser     = mysqlUser;
    this->mysqlPassword = mysqlPassword;
    this->mysqlIP       = "localhost";    //default
    this->mysqlPort     = 3306;           //default

    //Launch thread
    std::thread connectionThread(threadLoop);

}

Connection::~Connection(){
    mysqlConnection.disconnect();
}

void Connection::threadLoop(){
    //Connect to mySQL database
    mysqlConnection = new mysqlpp::Connection(false);

    if(mysqlConnection.connect(NULL, mysqlIP.c_str(), mysqlUser.c_str(), mysqlPassword.c_str(), mysqlPort)){
        std::string consulta = "SELECT * FROM 'Coordinates'";
        mysqlpp::Query query = mysqlConnection.query(consulta);
        mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store();
        query.reset();

    }

    while(true){
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal sample program. From your description, it should fit in 5-10 lines or so. See http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: Doesn't `std::thread`'s constructor expect a free function or at the very least a static member function? How can it know on which object to call `Connection::threadLoop`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: I think you should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti I don't know, I have been following a tutorial here and he does it just as simple as I am http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/

Comment: You are declaring an new thread object i n your constructor. I doubt this is what you intend.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why not? I mean,what's wrong with that?

Comment: It seems inconsistend with having a thread with the same name as a data member.

Comment: @RomanRdgz: Your `std::thread` will be destroyed when the `Connection` constructor finishes. This is, it will be destroyed immediately. Destructing an `std::thread` without joining it calls `terminate()`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Gorpik Well, the function is not finished yet, I was going to use join. Anyway thanks for your advice. Where would you put the std::thread then?

Comment: @Gorpik I am using a thread to do the dirty work just to get my GUI free from duties. If I call join after creating the thread, wouldn't it block there?

Comment: I'll write an answer explaining the whole mechanism, because it is a bit long for a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `threadLoop` is a member function, but there is no object for it to be applied to. Just guessing:

```
std::thread connectionThread(&Connection::threadLoop, this);
```

But that's just the syntactic issue; there's a logic problem, too: that line creates a local object of type `std::thread` that goes away when the function returns. Its destructor will call `std::terminate()` because the thread has not been joined. Most likely, this was supposed to attach a thread to the `connectionThread` member. To do that:

```
std::thread thr(threadLoop, this);
std::swap(thr, connectionThread);
```

Comment: In fact, the destructor does not throw, but calls `terminate()` directly, according to §30.3.1.3 in the standard. Not a good thing in any case. And this will also happen unless `connectionThread.join()` is eventually called.

Comment: It doesn't work, and I don't understand why must I pass a reference to the Connection class with "this": reference says that I should pass a function and optional arguments. Please explain if I am missing something

Comment: @RomanRdgz - in what way doesn't it work? A member function can only be called with an object. When you pass a pointer to member function into the `thread` constructor you must also give it an object. That can be an object itself, a reference to an object, a pointer to an object (such as `this`), or something that can be dereferenced to get a pointer or reference to an object (typically a smart pointer).

Comment: Thanks to @Dodgie for the correction of adding `&Connection::` to the construction of `connectionThread`. Don't know why the proposed edit was rejected.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has two problems:

1. You are providing incomplete information to the `std::thread` constructor
2. You are destroying the `std::thread` before it is joined with the main thread.

For the first problem, as [Pete Becker suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624271/c11-stdthread-giving-error-no-matching-function-to-call-stdthreadthread/12624993#12624993), you need to provide the object on which the function will be called, because the constructor for `std::thread` has no other way to know it. Assuming that you want to call function `threadLoop()` on the `Connection` object you are constructing, you can do this:

```
//Launch thread
std::thread connectionThread(threadLoop, this);
```

Internally, the constructor will call `this->threadLoop()` (where `this` is the `Connection*` parameter it received, not the `std::thread` itself, of course). And you will be fine.

The second problem is that your `std::thread` is destroyed immediately after starting, without having joined it to the main thread: this will call `terminate()`, which is not a good thing. Once again, Pete suggests a good alternative. Replace the above code with this:

```
// Launch thread
std::thread thr(threadLoop, this);
std::swap(thr, connectionThread);
```

The situation before this code is as follows:

- You have a trivial `std::thread` object, `connectionThread`, which does not really represent a thread

After executing the first line of code:

- You still have `connectionThread`
- You also have a live thread represented by the `std::thread` object `thr`, which will be destroyed at the end of the `Connection` constructor, causing a call to `terminate()` because it is never joined to the main thread.

Fortunately, the second line of code comes to the rescue. After executing it:

- You have a trivial `std::thread`, `thr`, which can be safely destroyed because it does not represent a real thread (so it is not joinable)
- You have a live thread represented by `connectionThread`, an object that will not be destroyed as long as the `Connection` object exists.

Now, the problem is that you want to join `connectionThread` to the main thread before it is destroyed, but you also want to avoid blocking the main thread. The right time to do this join is the latest possible time: when `connectionThread` is about to be destroyed. And this happens at the destructor of `Connection`. So we'll add a line to this destructor, this way:

```
Connection::~Connection(){
  mysqlConnection.disconnect();
  connectionThread.join(); // Now connectionThread can be safely destroyed
}
```

Besides, this is the safest place to call `join()`, because it ensures that you will never destroy an unjoined `connectionThread`. This is RAII in action; if you are not familiar with the concept of RAII (or RIIA, as it is sometimes called), you can find a lot of information about this very important concept in the web, including this site.

All this put together: creating a `Connection` object will create a new thread; in this thread, a new database connection will be established and a query will be executed, while the main thread remains free for whatever other use (for instance, managing the GUI). When the `Connection` object is finally destroyed, the main thread will wait for the additional thread to finish (if necessary) and then normal execution will continue. I hope this is what you wanted to accomplish with your code.

Answer (score 2):

As you may evince from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), `std::thread`'s constructor expect some form of function; you can pass it a free function, a static member function or one of these packed together with its arguments by means of [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). In order to execute a non-static member function you should use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to pass it together with the object it should be called on.

Comment: There's no need for `std::bind` or `std::men_fn` here; `std::thread`'s constructor knows how to deal with member functions. The problem is that there is no object for the member function to be applied to.

Comment: I see. I don't have the standard at hand and cppreference is not very clear on this subject.

Comment: cppreference is quite clear, but it's wrong. <g> For TR1, we invented the INVOKE terminology to describe how `bind` and `function` deal with various callable types, including pointers to member functions (the second argument has to be an object, a reference to an object, or a pointer to an object of a suitable type). `std::thread::thread(Fn&&, Args&&...)` uses the same mechanism.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I am reading the standard now and see that you are right. And now I read your comment and see that you had already explained the mechanism :)

Comment: I don't understand why giving std::thread() a free function works, and using a function declared into a class doesn't. Anyway, If I did my function free, out from the class, it still doesn't work

Comment: For the same reason why you cannot call it from outside its class by itself, as in `threadLoop()`, but you have to specify an instance of `Connection` on which to call it, as in `Connection().threadLoop()`.